# GPG change symmetric encryption password

Tags: shell, unix, encryption, command-line, gnupg

I'm trying to figure out a way to change the password of a file that is symmetrically encrypted by GPG without using a temporary file or a shell variable. I know I could do this in a shell function with a variable but I'd like to do it on the command line if possible.

I think this should be possible because GPG will encrypt incoming streams with `gpg --symmetric -o example.gpg` and because GPG will send decrypted output to STDOUT with `gpg --decrypt`.

But this doesn't work properly:

```
gpg --decrypt example.gpg | gpg --symmetric -o new.gpg
```

I think my understanding of the shell order of operations and redirection is wrong. Especially because the shell output has more than one `Enter passphrase:` prompts at a time.

Here is the initial interactive response after entering the piped commands:

```
localhost ~% gpg --decrypt example.gpg | gpg --symmetric -o example.gpg
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
Enter passphrase: Enter passphrase
```

After that, I get a variety of password prompts... sometimes I am asked for the decryption password, then I can type the new password in visible plain text, then the new password confirmation which is hidden. Sometimes, I get the new password dialogue before I am asked for the decryption password.

I think there is a race condition.

Any advice?

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution:

You need to non-interactively tell the first gpg command what the decryption passphrase is.

- With gpg2 (most modern Linux distros ship with this) it could look like this:

  ```
  gpg --decrypt --batch --passphrase 'original passwd' example.gpg  | gpg --symmetric -o new_example.gpg
  ```
- With gpg1, you would use `--no-use-agent` instead of `--batch`, e.g.:

  ```
  gpg -d --no-use-agent --passphrase 'original passwd' example.gpg  | gpg -co new_example.gpg
  ```

*Note: Depending on your version of gpg and how it's configured, you might also have to specify the passphrase in the same way for the second gpg command.*

### Root cause:

When you put together a commandline with pipes, your shell starts all the commands at the same time after setting up pipes to connect each one (to allow `stdout` of each command to be sent to `stdin` of the next).

### Extra warnings:

1. Do not write to the same file you're reading from. It will almost never work out how you want.
2. On a multi-user system it's a bad idea to use gpg's `--passphrase` option, since it makes the passphrase available for inspection by anyone on the system (anyone can run a `ps` command and see the passphrase while the `gpg` command is running). Furthermore, the passphrase is then saved in your shell history. Yikes. If that's a problem, use `--passphrase-fd` or `--passphrase-file`.